# Model Loses all Vertex Color in Render

Tags: rendering, materials, blender-internal-render-engine, vertex-colors

I have colored my model in Vertex Paint mode, but it loses all coloring once I switch to Render. How do I go about making the color show up when I render it?

Comment: please share screenshots and .blend file

Comment: how do you guys usually do that?

Comment: blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com then provide the link under "share this file"

Comment: This is a really general question. I have multiple models where this problem exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In object mode select the object that you would like to color, then add a material to that object. In the materials options panel, scroll down until you reach the **Vertex Color Paint** checkbox.

Once you check that, then all the color you add in the Vertex Pain mode will be rendered.

> Blender v2.76

Answer (score 2):

Let's say this is the object you have:
[image: Vertex Paint]

Now open up the node editor:
[image: Node Editor]

Add the material then, in the node editor add the `Attribute` node:
[image: Attribute Node]

Change the attribute label to `Col`:
[image: Col Attribute]

Then it will show up in both the material view:
[image: Material View]

And the Render View:
[image: Render View]

Hope this helps

---

Regards
Grimlock

Comment: I looked at what you said, but I don't have nearly as many options in the Node editor as you do, do you have some add-ons installed that I need?

Comment: No, but if you go to the node editor press shift+A and hit enter on search. Type in Attribute and u should find the attribute node

Comment: The above is correct for using Cycles renderer, and the solution below that was accepted is correct for Blender Render material.

Comment: @Craig D Jones Thank you for your clarification